# Phonegap - iPad unresponsive when launched in landscape & home button to the left

Tags: ipad, cordova, landscape

We are experiencing an issue with our application freezing when launched from the iPad while it is in landscape and the home button is on the left.  This is only affecting iPads, (not iPhones nor any other android device).  It is only an issue when you launch the application.  Launching in portrait mode does not freeze the app, nor landscape mode with the home button on the right.  Launching it from portrait successfully then switching to landscape with the button on the left presents no issues either.

We experience the freezing even when Hydra opens after it has detected a new update.  We are unable to select either options in Hydra; Update & restart/ignore.

We have tested installing without Hydra and still have freezing.
We are using PhoneGap 3.3.
The issue is not reproducible using a test hello world application.

There is one scrollable area of our application home screen that seems to be responsive, allowing us to scroll, but that is all.  No other area of the screen is responsive.

Has anybody seen anything like this before, or could anybody help point us in the right direction for trouble shooting.